# React- Why do all image modals render the same image when mapping over images?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react app. In the app on one page I am rendering images on the page, all images are different. To do this I am mapping over the images. When you click on an image, a modal appears with a larger version of the image, except all the images are the same image (which is the last image in my array). Why??

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

/* Components */
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const myComponent = () => {
    
    // controls for image modals
    const [showImageModal, setShowImageModal] = useState(false);
    const handleCloseImageModal = () => setShowImageModal(false);
    const handleShowImageModal = () => setShowImageModal(true);

    const imageURLs = {code to read images from directory goes here. This is working!}

    return (
        <>
            {imageURLs.map((url) => (
                <>
                   {/* The follow line works! Images are rendered correctly on the screen */}
                   <Button className='modalButton' onClick={handleShowImageModal}><img src={require(`../../uploadedImages/${url}`).default} className='imageCards'></img></Button>
                   
                   {/* The following lines render a modal but all modal images are the same */}
                   <Modal show={showImageModal} onHide={handleCloseImageModal}>
                        <img src={require(`../../uploadedImages/${url}`).default}></img>
                   </Modal>
                </>
             ))}
        </>
     )
  }
export default myComponent;
```

Just to give an idea of the results, the images on the component render correctly:
[image]

But when clicking to see a modal, they all are the same image:
[image]

Comment: Hard to test without a Sandbox because of your local files but I am pretty sure it may have something to do with missing keys on you components? Edit: I am actually not sure at all but it could be a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modals are correct, you're just showing *all five of them* at the same time.  Consider the state value(s) you're tracking.  You have five modals, but only *one* boolean value indicating if those modals are shown/hidden:

```
const [showImageModal, setShowImageModal] = useState(false);
```

So either *all of them* are shown or *all of them* are hidden.  Instead, track *which* modal you want to show or hide.  You could do this by tracking a unique identifier for them instead of just a boolean value.  For example, if `url` is the unique identifier:

```
// default to undefined so they're all hidden
const [showImageModal, setShowImageModal] = useState();
```

Then update to the `url` of the modal clicked on:

```
const handleShowImageModal = (url) => setShowImageModal(url);
```

Which you'd pass to the function:

```
<Button className='modalButton' onClick={() => handleShowImageModal(url)}>
```

And the modal itself would show if the state value matches its `url`:

```
<Modal show={showImageModal === url} onHide={handleCloseImageModal}>
```

Then hiding them would just be a matter of setting the value back to `undefined`:

```
const handleCloseImageModal = () => setShowImageModal(undefined);
```